# tikz-datavisualization not rendering data when inside onslide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-datavisualization

When inside a onslide the data is not renderered.

Any hint or workaround ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Foo}
  
    \onslide<1->{
      No data displayed:
      
    \tikz \datavisualization
  [scientific axes=clean,
   visualize as scatter/.list={a,b,c},
   style sheet=cross marks]
data [format=named] {
  x=0,       y={1,2,3},        set=a
  x={2,3,4}, y={3,4,5,7},      set=b
  x=6,       y={5,7,...,15},   set=c
};
    }

    
    Data displayed:
    
    \tikz \datavisualization
  [scientific axes=clean,
   visualize as scatter/.list={a,b,c},
   style sheet=cross marks]
data [format=named] {
  x=0,       y={1,2,3},        set=a
  x={2,3,4}, y={3,4,5,7},      set=b
  x=6,       y={5,7,...,15},   set=c
};


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem by using `uncoverenv`, `onlyenv` and similar environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Foo}
  
\begin{uncoverenv}<1->
      No data displayed:
      
    \tikz \datavisualization
  [scientific axes=clean,
   visualize as scatter/.list={a,b,c},
   style sheet=cross marks]
data [format=named] {
  x=0,       y={1,2,3},        set=a
  x={2,3,4}, y={3,4,5,7},      set=b
  x=6,       y={5,7,...,15},   set=c
};
\end{uncoverenv}
    
    Data displayed:
    
    \tikz \datavisualization
  [scientific axes=clean,
   visualize as scatter/.list={a,b,c},
   style sheet=cross marks]
data [format=named] {
  x=0,       y={1,2,3},        set=a
  x={2,3,4}, y={3,4,5,7},      set=b
  x=6,       y={5,7,...,15},   set=c
};


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```